# Nodejs mongodb insert with collection reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reference, insert, schema

I'm starting on node js and mogodb and I have to insert a collection with a reference for a another collection as shown in the example below:

```
var conn = require('../dbbase/dbconnection').conn; 

var Schema = conn.Schema;

var PerfilSchema = new Schema({
  nome:       { type: String, default: '' },
  descricao:  { type: String, default: '' },
  role:       { type: String, default: '' },
  created:    { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  nome:       { type: String, default: '' },
  descricao:  { type: String, default: '' },
  **perfil:     { type: String, default: '' },**
  created:    { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

As i show. I need insert user and pass a objectid perfil for reference for Perfil. any exemplo ?

Thanks alot.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? what is your problem? what have your tried so far?

Comment: I just, insert a user but i need set a perfil inside user maybe:

{
  nome:'helio',
  descricao: 'employer',
  perfil:{objectid:38478923948792} <- reference ate collection perfil
}